# Erase all contents of cc2650 from contiki using command

Tags: c, contiki, texas-instruments

I can upload my compiled code to TI cc2650 using the following command:

```
make TARGET=srf06-cc26xx BOARD=launchpad/cc2650 savetarget
sudo make PORT=/dev/ttyACM0 BOARD=launchpad/cc2650 hello-world.upload
```

and able to view its output on terminal using following command:

```
sudo make login PORT=/dev/ttyACM0
```

But when I try to re-upload the compiled code after making some edits following error is displayed:

```
using saved target 'srf06-cc26xx'
  CC        ../../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/lib/cc26xxware/startup_files/ccfg.c
  CC        ../../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/./ieee-addr.c
  AR        contiki-srf06-cc26xx.a
  CC        ../../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/./fault-handlers.c
  CC        ../../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/lib/cc26xxware/startup_files/startup_gcc.c
  CC        client.c
  LD        client.elf
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary --gap-fill 0xff client.elf client.bin
python ../../../tools/cc2538-bsl/cc2538-bsl.py -e -w -v -p /dev/ttyACM0 client.bin
Opening port /dev/ttyACM0, baud 500000
Reading data from client.bin
Cannot auto-detect firmware filetype: Assuming .bin
Connecting to target...
ERROR: Timeout waiting for ACK/NACK after 'Synch (0x55 0x55)'
make: *** [client.upload] Error 1
rm client.co obj_srf06-cc26xx/fault-handlers.o obj_srf06-cc26xx/startup_gcc.o
```

This works fine if I erase the contents of TIcc2650 using `SmartRF Flash Programmer` software and then try to upload code from contiki using above commands.

Can someone guide how to I can erase the contents directly from some commands instead of using `SmartRF Flash Programmer` software?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SmartRF_INSTALL_DIR/bin/srfprog` as a command line executable. You can check its help menu

```
Texas Instruments SmartRF Flash Programmer 2 v1.8.0-windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The following Command Line Options are supported by the Flash Programmer
>srfprog [Target] [Actions] [File] [Address]

The order of the parameters is irrelevant.

Description of a specific option can be obtained with:
>srfprog -h [target | actions | file | address | example | help]
Only the two first letters are required: E.g.: srfprog -h ta

Help notation:
[]  Square brackets are used for optional parameters.
%%  Percentage mark used for symbols to be replaced.
{}  Curly brackets used where one of the options are required.
|   Vertical bars for choice of items.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Target: {-t | --target} [soc | lsidx]

   soc(%device id%[, %chip id%])  SoC Device
       %device id%: Device ID of connected EB. This parameter is case sensitive.
       %chip id%:   Chip ID. If not given for XDS emulator devices,
                    probing to determine the connected SoC will be
                    performed and this will take longer time.
                    Chip ID is mandatory in combination with COM devices.

   lsidx(%index%)  List index
      %index%:     Index of connected device returned from a list command.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Actions: [-ls | --list] | [-e | --erase] | [-p | --program] |
         [-v | --verify] | [-r | --read] | [-w | --write] |
         [-k | --keep] | [-c | --change] | [-rs | --reset] |
         [-j4 | --jtag4]

  {-ls | --list} [min | all | auto]
    min:  List connected Cebal devices(Default).
    all:  List all connected devices.
    auto: List all connected devices and automatically try to find the chip id
          for ARM based devices.

  {-e | --erase} [all | p | pif | epfw | ep | forced]
    all:         Erase all unprotected pages(Default).
    p(%pages%):  Erase given pages.
    pif:         Erase pages in source file.
    forced:      Forced Mass erase. Cannot be combined with
                 other actions.

  {-p | --program} [all | epfw | ep]
    all:           Program all pages in source file(Default).
    epfw(%value%): Exclude pages from source file filled with given value.
    ep(%pages%):   Exclude given pages from source file.

  {-v | --verify} [crc | rb] [pif | all | epfw | ep]
    crc:           Verify pages using CRC checksum(Default).
    rb:            Verify pages using readback and bytewise comparison.

    all:           Verify all pages in source file (Default).
    epfw(%value%): Exclude pages from source file filled with given value.
    ep(%pages%):   Exclude given pages.

  {-r | --read} [all | p | addr | macpri | macpri154 | macprible |
                 macsec | macsec154 | macsecble]
    all:           Read all pages(Default). Output to file.
    p(%pages%):    Read given pages. Output to file.
    addr(0x%address%,%length%):
                   Read from given address with given length.
    macpri:        Read Primary IEEE 802.15.4 MAC Address.
    macpri154:     Read Primary IEEE 802.15.4 MAC Address.
    macprible:     Read Primary BLE MAC Address.
    macsec:        Read Secondary IEEE 802.15.4 MAC Address.
    macsec154:     Read Secondary IEEE 802.15.4 MAC Address.
    macsecble:     Read Secondary BLE MAC Address.

  {-w | --write} {macpri | macsec | macsec154 | macsecble | ccfg | addr | p}
    macpri=01.02.03.04.05.06.07.08:
                   Program Primary IEEE 802.15.4 MAC address.
                   Write of primary address only supported for CC2538 and
                   only if information page is not locked.
    macsec=01.02.03.04.05.06.07.08 or
    macsec154=01.02.03.04.05.06.07.08:
                  Program Secondary IEEE 802.15.4 MAC Address.
    macsecble=01.02.03.04.05.06:
                  Program Secondary BLE MAC Address.
    ccfg({wpp(%pages%) | ldbg | disbl})
          Combinations of the following options are possible and must be separated
          by a ','
          wpp=%pages%: Program CCFG area with page lock
                        bits for the given pages.
          ldbg:         Program CCFG area with bit for
                        locking debug interface
          disbl:        Program CCFG area with bit for
                        disabling the bootloader interface
    addr(0x%address%,%length%)=0x%value%
          Fill the an address range in flash with the given value.
          The value must be given as a one byte hexadecimal number
    p(%pages%)=0x%value%
          Fill the a page range in flash with the given value.
          The value must be given as a one byte hexadecimal number

  {-k | --keep} {mac | macble | mac154&macble | ccfg}
    mac:           Keep(or Retain) IEEE Mac address from Target device.
    macble:        Keep(or Retain) Ble Mac address from Target device.
    mac154&macble: Keep(or Retain) IEE and Ble Mac address from Target device.
    ccfg:          Keep(or Retain) Complete CCFG area from Target device.

  {-c | --change} {mac | mac154 | macble | efk | ldbg | wpp | disbl}
    Combinations of options are possible and must be separated
    by a ','
    mac=01.02.03.04.05.06.07.08 or
    mac154=01.02.03.04.05.06.07.08:
                   Change(patch) flash image with IEEE 802.15.4 MAC address.
    macble=01.02.03.04.05.06:
                   Change(patch) flash image with BLE MAC address.
    mac154=01.02.03.04.05.06.07.08 macble=01.02.03.04.05.06:
                   Change(patch) flash image with both addresses.
    ekf(%file%, %address%):
                   Change(patch) flash image with Encryption Key data.
                   A file with the encryption key certificate and the flash
                   address must be given.
    wpp(%pages%):
                   Change(patch) CCFG area in flash image with page lock
                   bits for the given pages.
    ldbg:
                   Change(patch) CCFG area in flash image with bit for
                   locking debug interface
    disbl:
                   Change(patch) CCFG area in flash image with bit for
                   disabling the bootloader interface

  {-rs | --reset}  [normal | none | pin | pinHib]
    Pin reset is default.
    Please refer to the help documentation for a detailed
    description of the different reset options.
    The reset action must be combined with the erase or program action.

  {-j4 | --jtag4}
    Use 4-pin jtag. 2-pin cJTAG is default.

  {-up | --updateEmulator}
    Update firmware on emulator. Option is applicable for XDS110, and cannot be
    combined with other actions. Do not unplug the debug probe during the update.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File: {-f | --file} %file%

   %file%:  Full or relative path. E.g. C:\myfolder\test.bin.
            Path name with spaces must be enclosed between quote characters.
            E.g. "C:\myfolder\my test.bin"
            or   "C:\Program files\myfolder\test.bin"
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Address: {-a | --address} [0x]%address%

  %address%: Flash address to start programming.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Examples:

>srfprog -ls
>srfprog -ls all
>srfprog -ls auto
>srfprog -t lsidx(0) -e all
>srfprog -t lsidx(0) -r macsec
>srfprog -t lsidx(0) -r all -f C:\myfolder\readback.bin
>srfprog -t lsidx(0) -r p(0-4) -f C:\myfolder\readback.bin
>srfprog -t lsidx(0) -r addr(0x200000,8)
>srfprog -t lsidx(0) -w macsec=01.02.03.04.05.06.07.08
>srfprog -t lsidx(0) -e pif -p epfw(0) -f C:\myfolder\test.bin -a 0x200000
>srfprog -t lsidx(0) -e pif -p epfw(0) -v rb -f C:\myfolder\test.bin -a 0x200000
>srfprog -t lsidx(0) -e all -p -v rb epfw(0x55) -f C:\myfolder\test.bin -a 0x200000
>srfprog -t lsidx(0) -e all -p -v rb ep(0-1) -f C:\myfolder\test.bin -a 0x200000
>srfprog -t lsidx(0) -e pif -p epfw(0) -v crc -f C:\myfolder\test.bin -a 0x200000 -k mac
>srfprog -t lsidx(0) -e pif -p epfw(0) -v crc -f C:\myfolder\test.bin -a 0x200000 -c mac=01.02.03.04.05.06.07.08        >srfprog -t lsidx(0) -e pif -p epfw(0) -v crc -f C:\myfolder\test.hex -c ekf(C:\myfolder\certificate.txt, 0x27FF6C)     >srfprog -t soc(XDS-06EB12100300A,CC2538) -e -p -v -f c:\test.hex
>srfprog -t soc(COM1, CC2640) -e -p -v -f c:\test.hex
```

Comment: I want to erase the content directly from a "contiki" command